# Content in Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fpybzp4/2/)

I have built the reusable directive  which can be used wherever needed. But the text in the directive will be updated from JSON file. I have created a object named obj in which my text is stored. Suppose if the **form name is verification** then i want to add **condition1** as a text but if form name is **bankterms** then i want to text as **condition2**.

HTML

```
<div ng-app='demo'>
<form name="verification" ng-controller="myCtrl1">

    <terms-conditions conditions="conditions" checked="checked"></terms-conditions>   <br>
    <button class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked" >Submit</button>
      <hr>


</form>

    <form name="bankinfo" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
          <terms-conditions conditions="conditions" checked="checked"></terms-conditions>  <br>
       <button class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked">Submit</button>
      <hr>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span {
font-weight:bold;
}
.terms{font-weight: normal;
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #666666;
border-width: 1px;}
```

js

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
var data= {
condition1:"Payments terms",
condition2:"Bank terms"
}
demo.directive("termsConditions",function(){
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        conditions:'=',
        checked:'='
    },
    template:
    "<div class='terms row'><span class='col-md-12'>{{data.condition1}}</span></div><br><input type='checkbox' ng-model='checked'><span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>"
}

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage all the goodies of Angular's build-in [`form`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) directive and play together with it.

The main idea is to require your directive to be inside a `form` directive with `require: '^form'`, that will allow you to use the same controller as `form` directive defines in you link function (as forth argument), make a `controller.$name` magic and check if the form is valid or not with `<form_name>.$valid` condition. In order to tell `form` directive checkbox is required, all you need is to place `required` attribute on it. That will also allow to avoid additional logic inside your controller for validating each form.

Besides of it, if you care about performance, don't define unnecessary data bindings via your directive scope. Actually for your case you don't need isolated scope either - just a child scope will be enough (`scope:true`). In order to get all conditions once from your parent scope, you can use [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service.

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.conditions = {
      'verification': 'T&C for verification',
      'bankInfo': 'T&C for bank info'
    }
  }]).
  directive('termsConditions', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^form',
      template: '<div>' +
                  '<textarea>{{termsAndConditions}}</textarea>' +
                  '<br/>' +
                  '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" required><span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>' +
                '</div>',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
        scope.termsAndConditions = $interpolate('{{'+ iAttrs.conditions + '["' + controller.$name + '"]}}')(scope);
      }
    }
  }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="verification">
  <terms-conditions conditions="conditions"></terms-conditions>
  <button ng-disabled="!verification.$valid">Submit</button>
</form>

<form name="bankInfo">
  <terms-conditions conditions="conditions"></terms-conditions>
  <button ng-disabled="!bankInfo.$valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/S5uCQjvRfwwAOC8s6itE?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Set up your own controller, then inside the controller when it loads, automatically run a function which checks the name of the form and sets the data object property to the proper text. You only need one property "condition" instead of two separate ones. You can just change the text of the property inside the function as mentioned above. Technically you don't even need a controller, but it's good practice.

```
function () {

  var getFormName = /* get your form name however you want */;

  if (getFormName == 'verification') {
    data.condition = 'Payments terms';
  } else if (getFormName == 'bankterms') {
    data.condition = 'Bank terms';
  }

}
```

Comment: Can we create that controller in directive itself? So that Whole directive can have its own controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to pass all of your conditions into the directive, keep it simple and just pass the condition that you want to display

http://jsfiddle.net/frgjqu0s/

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
var data= {
    condition1:"Payments terms",
    condition2:"Bank terms"
}
demo.directive("termsConditions",function(){
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        scope:{
            condition:'@',
            checked:'='
        },
        template:
        "<div class='terms row'>" + 
        "<span class='col-md-12'>{{condition}}</span>" + 
        "</div><br>" + 
        "<input type='checkbox' ng-model='checked'>" +
        "<span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>"
    }

});

demo.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope){
    if ('YOUR LOGIC' == 'YOUR LOGIC'){
        $scope.condition = data.condition1;
    }
});

demo.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope){
    if ('YOUR LOGIC' == 'YOUR LOGIC'){
        $scope.condition = data.condition2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we create that controller in directive itself? So that Whole directive can have its own controller. ?

Comment: Usually people use a linking function for something like that.  I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is but here's a different approach. It uses a linking function and hardcodes the text in the template instead of passing it around http://jsfiddle.net/wrLy8eb3/